# First order DE problem, finding a set of curves that satisfy a condition.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem goes like this:
Find the curves that satisfy that the area under the curve in point (1,1) and any other point (x,y)(both in the curve), is equal to the area of a triangle with vertices (0,0),(x,y) and (x,0) plus 6.
Now I wrote the equation which goes like this:
\begin{equation}
\int_1^xf(x) dx=\dfrac{xy}{2}+6
\end{equation}
How can i work with the integral so that the equation becomes a 1st order DE? and then by integration i can find the curve that satisfies the condition

Comment: Is it your intention that $y = f(x)$?

Comment: yes that's the intention so that is posible to find a solution for y, and then solve for the curves.

Comment: rewriting the equation again, knowing that the vertice $(x,y)$ can be represented as $(x,f(x)$ $\int_1^x f(x)dx = \dfrac{x f(x)}{2}+6$